# Could Earth's magnetic field be used to lift electromagnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, earth, levitation, geomagnetism

[image: electromagnet levitation]

This but lifted by the Earth's magnetic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A magnet (including an electromagnet) in a uniform magnetic field feels a torque (twist) but no net linear force (thrust).  It is only when the external field varies (in magnitude and/or direction) that when you average over an entire magnet you get an unbalanced linear force.

When you have two magnets in your hand, you can feel them pushing, pulling, twisting against each other.  The magnetic field close to a magnet varies a lot in a short distance: think of those pictures where the field lines come out of one pole, rapidly turn around and go the other way, and then turn around again to go into the other pole.

If you draw the same picture for the Earth, you see that it takes hundreds or thousands of miles for the magnetic field to bend a little. If you look at Earth's field over the size of your levitation device, it varies almost not at all.

Hang a magnet, say a compass needle, from a long thread so it can move freely.  The North-seeking-pole is pulled to the North, and the South-seeking-pole is pulled to the South, so the compass needle twists and points North-South.  However, the two poles are pulled in opposite directions with the same force, so there is no net linear force, and the thread hangs straight up-and-down.